# C# SQLite - do not cast data when reading

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am successfully reading data from a SQLite database in c#.

My problem comes from the following:

I leveraged the soft-typed aspect of SQLite to my advantage by updating certain integer values as the string they represent to save time down the line.

The entire process works perfectly but now I realize that the library in SQLiteCommand actually appears to recast the data to int, therefore ruining my result set.

Is there a way around this?

It appears possible due to the fact that I use SQLiteMan to view my data and the casting is maintained perfectly here, but I know this is in c++.

Thanks for the pointers

Comment: Are you referring to [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/), or the [C# port of SQLite](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/)?

Comment: Please add a short code example to your question that reproduces the problem you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your SQLite field to TEXT affinity.  See http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity

Comment: Yes but it seems as if in SQLite that you cannot set the affinity after the table has been created?

Comment: Then I guess you need to create a new table and copy the existing data over to it.